# Image gets resized and jerky on website load

Tags: wordpress, image-resizing, web-testing

I manage a website for my firm and am unable to fix an error that gives it a sudden jerk to the main image on home page after movement of mouse. Same happens on other pages of site when I scroll down on mobile i.e. the content gets a jerk after first movement on screen.

- [Home Page](https://www.pacificeducation.in/) --> Which has large image resizing & jerk issue
- [Other Page](https://www.pacificeducation.in/mbbs-fees-in-russia/) --> Sample page that has a jerk issue and all other pages have this issue)

Any suggestion for fixing it would be appreciated.

Thanks.

As I am working in Wordpress, so I have tried to disable all plugin one by one and then enabled and tested with each of them.

But yet, nothing seems to fix this issue.